# Align right inside block

Tags: css

I have a template which has 4 list items for some links. I minimized them to 2 and want to put country flags to both sides. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of nice list item]

When I grow the page the flag seems left part of the item:

[image: Screenshot of bad list item]

Here's my code:

```
<li><a class="active">Türkçe<img style="position: absolute; height: 23px; width: 34px; top: 0.15em; margin-left: 12%; margin-right: auto;" src="./images/turkey-flag2.jpg" /></a></li>
```

How can I put the flag to the right side of the item?

Comment: We need to see the rest of your code to help you.  It's most likely that The relevant styling would be in the container of the flag, not the flag itself.

Comment: The background-position CSS property sets the initial position for each background image.

Comment: Can I paste jsfiddle here?